# RichTextEditBox and LinkLabel winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, linklabel

I am using a windows forms RichTextEditBox. I load a RTF file into the control. I then set the following code.

```
 int indexToText = rteb.Find("here");

 LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
 link.Text = "here";
 link.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.AlwaysUnderline;
 link.LinkClicked += new 
     LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.link_LinkClicked);

 LinkLabel.Link data = new LinkLabel.Link();
 data.LinkData = "Sending Report Results to Multiple Recipients.pdf";
 link.Links.Add(data);

 link.AutoSize = true;
 link.Location = rteb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(indexToText);
 link.Height = 40;
 link.Width = 60;
 link.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
 rteb.Controls.Add(link);
```

when the app is run, the word "here" is in blue, but I don't get an underline and when I try clicking on the word, my click event doesn't fire off. What am I missing here?

Comment: Use a LinkLabel to provide a URL, similar to what you use in a browser.  A pdf file stored in an unknown directory does not help a browser to display it.  Consider file://c:\foo\bar\baz.pdf, but also consider that your user might not favor using his browser to read a pdf file.  Process.Start() is a decent alternative.

Comment: Sorry i didn't show my LinkClicked event but I am using Process.Start() to display the pdf file. But that is not the issue. The issue is when I click on the word "here" nothing happens. It does not act like a link. No LinkClicked event fires off.

Answer (score 0):

To set an underlined link area in `LinkLabel` you should set [`LinkArea`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkarea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property to the range which should be shown as link, for example:

```
LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
link.Text = "here";
link.LinkArea = new LinkArea(0, link.Text.Length);
link.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.AlwaysUnderline;
```

Comment: Just added that and still nothing happens. I click on the word "here" and my linkClicked event does not fire off

Comment: I tried it. It works properly and it's really simple to test :)

Comment: May I see your code . I have tried everything and it doesn't fire off the event for me. Now the difference between our samples is probably that i am loading a microsoft word rtf file.

Comment: If you are going to use `Links` collection, you can set `data.Start = 0; data.Length = link.Text.Length;`. I also tested this and it's working well as well.